# After clearing file input, image preview fails to load when uploading new files

Tags: javascript, html, image, file, input

I currently have a file input which is replaced or cleared once the user clicks on a "clear" link. When a user uploads images, the images are displayed as thumbnails under the input button. The problem is when I clear/replace the input and preview section, new pictures that are loaded do not display as a preview.

```
<!-- File Upload Section BEGIN -->
<label for="control">
    <span class="btn">Add Images</span>
</label> 
<input style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" class="imagefet" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="control" multiple="multiple">

<br><div class="output-fet"><output id="list"></output></div>

<a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){

    //IMAGE PREVIEW FUNCTION
    var count=0;
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var $fileUpload = $(".imagefet");
        count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);

        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 5 || count>4) {
            alert("You can only upload a maximum of 4 files");
            count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
        var files = evt.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    $('.imagefet').change(function(evt){
        handleFileSelect(evt);
    });  

    // CLEAR FUNCTION    
    $("#clear").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#control").replaceWith('<input style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" class="imagefet" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="control" multiple="multiple">');
      $("div.output-fet").replaceWith('<div class="output-fet"><output id="list"></output></div>');
    });


    })
</script>
```

[image]

FIXED Corrected code below

```
<!-- File Upload Section BEGIN -->
<label for="control">
    <span class="btn">Add Images</span>
</label> 
<input style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" class="imagefet" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="control" multiple="multiple">

<br><div class="output-fet"><output id="list"></output></div>

<a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){

    //IMAGE PREVIEW FUNCTION
    var count=0;
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var $fileUpload = $(".imagefet");
        count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);

        if (count>4) {
            alert("You can only upload a maximum of 4 files");
            count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
        var files = evt.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    $('.imagefet').change(function(evt){
        handleFileSelect(evt);
    });  

    // CLEAR FUNCTION    
    $("#clear").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#control").replaceWith('<input style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" class="imagefet" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="control" multiple="multiple">');
      $("div.output-fet").replaceWith('<div class="output-fet"><output id="list"></output></div>');
       $('.imagefet').change(function(evt) {
          handleFileSelect(evt);
            count = 0;
        });
    });


    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work the 2nd time because `.imagefet` was destroyed by the click handler. One way to solve it is to reattach `handleFileSelect` on the new `.imagefet`, by appending the following lines to `.click`:

```
$('.imagefet').change(function(evt) {
  handleFileSelect(evt);
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  //IMAGE PREVIEW FUNCTION
  var count = 0;

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var $fileUpload = $(".imagefet");
    count = count + parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);

    if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 5 || count > 4) {
      alert("You can only upload a maximum of 4 files");
      count = count - parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  $('.imagefet').change(function(evt) {
    handleFileSelect(evt);
  });

  // CLEAR FUNCTION    
  $("#clear").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#control").replaceWith('<input style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" class="imagefet" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="control" multiple="multiple">');
    $("div.output-fet").replaceWith('<div class="output-fet"><output id="list"></output></div>');
    $('.imagefet').change(function(evt) {
      handleFileSelect(evt);
    });
  });



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- File Upload Section BEGIN -->
<label for="control">
  <span class="btn">Add Images</span>
</label>
<input style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" class="imagefet" type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="control" multiple="multiple">

<br>
<div class="output-fet">
  <output id="list"></output>
</div>

<a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks so much.